# ¿Por qué "recordar" es transitivo pero "acordar(se)" intransitivo pronominal?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, verbo-pronominal

El otro día me fijé en que estas dos frases son equivalentes:

> No **recuerdo** dónde dejé las llaves
>
> No **me acuerdo de** dónde dejé las llaves

En una usamos el verbo *recordar* en modo transitivo, mientras que en otra *acordar(se)* es intransitivo pronominal. En ambos casos el uso es el mismo, de acuerdo con las definiciones del DLE:

> [**recordar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VV3nlWy)
>   1. tr. Pasar a tener en la mente algo del pasado. *Ahora lo recuerdo: ella no vino ese día*. U. t. c. intr. *Aquí jugábamos de niños, ¿recuerdas?*
>
> [**acordar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0ZKiQZ3)
>   13. prnl. Recordar o tener en la memoria algo o a alguien. Acordarse DE un hijo ausente. *Acuérdese DE que nos debe dinero*. Era u. t. c. tr.

(nótese que el DLE indica *era usado también como transitivo*).

Luego el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas explica en su entrada [*recordar(se)*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=YxI5Ut9UDD6nZOBroE):

> Los verbos *recordar* y *acordar* comparten este significado, pero en la lengua general culta se construyen de modo diferente: recordar, como se acaba de explicar, es transitivo (*recordar* [algo]), mientras que acordar ([→ acordar(se), 3](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=R0RkhrRE2D6itXvKdn)) es intransitivo pronominal (*acordarse* de algo).

Así pues, ¿qué llevó a la forma *acordar* a pasar a ser comúnmente usado de forma intransitiva?

Comment: Similar a la diferencia entre "olvidar" (algo más formal) y "olvidarse de" (algo más informal): Olvidé dónde dejé las llaves vs. Me olvidé de dónde dejé las llaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En [esta página del DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=R0RkhrRE2D6itXvKdn) pueden encontrarse todos los usos de "recordar" y "acordarse de". Además de ser transitivo para introducir a la cosa recordada, "recordar" puede tener como objeto a la persona a quien se le trae algo a la memoria:

- Te recuerdo que es tu obligación.

En [este libro](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=sL_f_zp2hTYC&pg=PA352&lpg=PA352&dq=origen%20recordar%20%22acordarse%20de%22&source=bl&ots=CyVkzeUP90&sig=ACfU3U2lkai_d1f1B3whQIUDlRz2K5sLyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHxe2Js6bkAhWEHrkGHZtjAc04ChDoATACegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=origen%20recordar%20%22acordarse%20de%22&f=false) se hace referencia al origen común de ambas palabras:

> [image]
>
> *Acordarse de* como verbo de «recuerdo» fue una creación relativamente tardía del castellano, a partir de *recordar(se)* (verbos ambos de un mismo origen etimológico): si *recordar* tomoó el sentido de «volver en sí, despertar» que tenía *acordar*<sup>13</sup>, este último adoptó el sentido, y el esquema sintáctico, de *recordar(se)*. Posteriormente, *recordar(se)* quedó como forma vulgar, y sólo se aceptó *acordarse de*.

Comment: Qué interesante que mencione que quedó como forma vulgar. Lo que no me queda claro es qué acepción exacta quedó marcada como tal, pues actualmente ambas son sinónimas.